# Questions to optimize Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I'm working with multiple tables, i think 50+, linked for main table, the main table contain only information, and the next tables contains a specific items, some tables have data per specific user, other only is null, other have all data, now I'm working with left join(now is very very bigger).
This consult sql is made per a web php, and return a json, and i show it with Angularjs, so i call it only one time, because my web only load one time,  my question is,

1. How optimal is to do this? Because some time the result is big.

   - It would be more efficient to query for each table?
   - Exist other method for do it?
2. Maybe i can make a Vertical Menu for group all data, but i think is necessary do the same sentence , right?

   - if is not, them is more efficient, call many time a little left join, because if i have a preload data, i can call only specific tables, or is more efficient call all data one time and filter, route, hide , show with Angularjs.
   - if is Yes, other solution.

The conclusion of my question may be, to do to work in the most efficient manner with multiple tables.

Like a example please [check this web](http://sports.sportium.es/es/football) you can see many match grouped by sports, and next by country and next by league next, you can find a specific match e.g. Team A vs Team B, but that match have a many bet types, and some matches have a specific bets type and other no have, i need something like.

```
ALL Matchs Packets{
                    Soccer{
                               France{
                                     Liga A:{
                                             Team A vs Team B{
                                                Bettype A{}
                                                Bettype V{}
                                                Bettype AA{}
                                                Bettype DD{}
                                              }
                                             Team C vs Team D{
....
                                              }   
                                             Team E vs Team F{
....
                                              }      
                                            }
                                     Liga B:{...}                                       
                                     Liga C:{...}
                                     }
                               Spain{
                                     Liga A:
                                     Liga B:
                                     Liga C:
                                     }
                               England{
                                     Liga A:
                                     Liga B:
                                     Liga C:
                                     }
                     },
                     Basket{
                     ...
                     ...
                     }

                   }
```

**Edit:** The Main Table contain Id_match, Sport,Country, League , Team A, Team B etc.
each bettype is 1 Table contain id_match and other specific data

Comment: sorry when i create the post i think in the lenguage but you have reason i change it, but i working with mysql

Comment: Please have a think and rewrite the question

Comment: Please only i need to know, if you have to make a web like the example, how would you do it?