# Mysql with multiple leftjoin

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

Hello I am working in [web like this](http://sports.sportium.es/es/football), with this structure

```
ALL Matchs Packets{
                    Soccer{
                               France{
                                     Liga A:{
                                             Team A vs Team B{
                                                Bettype A{}
                                                Bettype V{}
                                                Bettype AA{}
                                                Bettype DD{}
                                              }
                                             Team C vs Team D{
....
                                              }   
                                             Team E vs Team F{
....
                                              }      
                                            }
                                     Liga B:{...}                                       
                                     Liga C:{...}
                                     }
                               Spain{
                                     Liga A:
                                     Liga B:
                                     Liga C:
                                     }
                               England{
                                     Liga A:
                                     Liga B:
                                     Liga C:
                                     }
                     },
                     Basket{
                     ...
                     ...
                     }

                   }
```

I have a main table which contains the details of match,Id_match, Sport,Country, League , Team A, Team B etc. 
Additionally I have a table for each bettype and contain id_match and other specific data.
I am working with 50+ tables, my web is in php and the database is mysql. Then I make a consult with leftjoin, per each bettype(all leftjoin in 1 consult), and is linked with id_event, the result of my consult return json, and in my html5 I use angularjs for show.
Some matches have data for all tables, but other show null in some bettypes, that is okay, because each bettype is specific.
**I am using Angularjs then I need call to database only one time, because I can filter, hide, group, etc; on the client side**

**my fear is the optimization, I want to know if a consultation like this is fine, because, imagine doing this for 300 games and 60 tables with types of bets.**

I think in create a menu to filter the Sport->Country->league and only make the consult for this specific group, to do it, I only used my main table(only 1 table), but my question is, if many people call multiple times to the database,will occur the same wear? or this is the solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Questions to optimize Mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088783/questions-to-optimize-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Since visitor specific filtering will be on the client side, all visitors will get the same full dataset. The json file can be cached and updated e.g. every minute.
The load on the database will be independent of the number of visitors.

All data that needs joining but is rarely updated can be cached in a single table. Updated e.g. daily. The queries will be less complex and faster.